# How to have scrollable menu and pop-up animation as it is there in the Pixlr Android App?

Tags: android, android-animation, navigation-drawer, android-drawable

The app that I am making is a native Android App, though I wont be needing much of other animations, the primary thing that I will need is a scroll-able menu and post that when ever an item is clicked a drawer from the bottom should pull up.

As such, can you please suggest where to get started with these kind of features? Is there any existing free repository that have these already implemented?

[image: Scrollable menu]

[image: Drawer up animation]

Comment: use Scrollbar Horizontal or Vertical  there.

Answer (score 1):

Scrollable menu is nothing special. You may create a horizontal ScrollView and place your menu items inside of it. And implement a click listener for the menu items and execute the associated tasks with them. Here are some pointers.

```
<YOUR PARENT LAYOUT>
...
<HorizontalScrollView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
<!--Your Menu Items Here-->
</HorizontalScrollView>
...
</YOUR PARENT LAYOUT>
```

Finally Create a click listener

```
YourActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
...
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v.getId() == R.id.menuButton1) {
            // Do your task here
        }
    }
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks @subin-sebastian , but that is not all. If you can try out the app, when the user clicks on a item, it spawns out other sub-features. So, how is that animation done?